# Root of virtual directory is localhost, not localhost/myapp. So all my links are broken

Tags: iis

So I'm deploying a website on my local dev machine.  I created an application inside Default Web Site.  I can hit it with localhost/myapp and it loads index.html.  However, all the links (css, js etc) on index.html are calling localhost/whatever.css.  It's cutting off the /myapp bit.  Is there something I need to add to web.config?
FYI, I'm running Win10.  Site created with VS2015.  ASPNet5 app.

Comment: I'd like to know if you found a solution to this. It is my problem as well.

Answer (score 0):

In your index.html file you would have linked those `whatever.css` files using absolute path which starts with `/` - forward slash, like `/whatever.css`

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="/whatever.css">`

remove those forward slash for it to look like `whatever.css`.

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="whatever.css">`

This will fix the errors.

Comment: That doesn't work for me.  Take the example where whatever.css is in sub directory 'resources'.  I need to reference '/resources/whatever.css'.  But when I do that, the browser is requesting 'http://localhost/resources/whatever.css'  Which is a bad link because it dropped the /myapp.  It's like it has mapped the root back to localhost.

Comment: Same applies there, remove the forward slash from `/resources/whatever.css` to look like `resources/whatever.css`

Comment: I tried that, still requests localhost/resources/whatever.css

Comment: Is your directory structure looking like the following?

|-index.html
|-resources/
|--whatever.css

And also did you try using private browsing to test, web browsers cache files, so private browsing will help i suppose.

Comment: If I simply link to <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="whatever.css" />  I get a browser error calling http://localhost/whatever.css.   Even if I put whatever.css in the same directory as index.html (the root), It is a broken link requesting localhost/whatever.css.  It must be something I'm doing in startup.cs or webconfig.  It does work if I deploy to azure...